# pyldap DN encoding Error

Tags: python, django, encoding, ldap

I am using `pyldap` with django to query a MS AD.

In the AD there is a user object with the CN `Felix Häusler`.

The full DN includes the CN of course, which makes the DN of the user object contain the non-ascii character `ä`.

Trying to perform a search

`con.search_s(u'CN=Felix Häusler,OU=Management,...,DC=local', ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL, 'objectClass=person')`

I get the error

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)`

How do i need to escape the character or re-encode the string, in order to not get an ascii error and find the DN?

Comment: pyldap doesn't seem to handle Unicode characters correctly. https://github.com/pyldap/pyldap/issues/39

Comment: Opened a ticket on github and got the advice to switch to `bytes_mode=False` when initializing the connection.

Maybe this works well on Python 3, but on 2.7 there are most certainly encoding issues.